# Battery charge/discharge cycle

Tags: 16.04, power-management, laptop, battery

My battery behaves normally until its charge reaches down to 80%. After that, it begins a cycle of charging/discharging with 10s on each state.

Here is some data:

```
deimos@kami:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Simplo
  model:                Li_Ion_4000mA
  serial:               0004
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mar 03 oct 2017 16:59:24 AST (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              64.0803 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         70.4184 Wh
    energy-full-design:  73.26 Wh
    energy-rate:         2.8527 W
    voltage:             12.407 V
    time to full:        2.2 hours
    percentage:          90%
    capacity:            96.1212%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1507064364  2.853   unknown
    1507064358  7.232   discharging
    1507064348  2.464   charging
    1507064341  6.777   discharging
    1507064332  2.836   charging
    1507064323  6.799   discharging
    1507064313  3.974   charging
    1507064306  9.962   discharging
    1507064295  2.620   charging
    1507064280  6.629   discharging
    1507064260  3.119   charging
    1507064259  15.473  discharging
```

When I start the laptop with no battery, running on direct power supply through AC adapter, everything works fine. It works fine with my old battery too.

I think it could be a driver's problem.

This is my Ubuntu information:

```
deimos@kami:~$ uname -a
Linux kami 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I watch the AC adapter status, it cycles from on-line/off-line.

UPDATES:
I bought two of these batteries and both have the same problem.
I tried to re-calibrate both batteries, but the problem remains.

How do I solve the issue?

Comment: "I start the laptop with my old battery, and everything works fine." This seems to imply an issue with the battery its self, not the software, the AC is fine, the other battery is fine and this one is fine until it reaches 80%.

Comment: It could be, but here is the thing. I bought two batteries, and the two of them have the same problem.

Comment: How new are these battery's? `capacity:  96.1212%` shows some degridation already but not as much as 20%

Comment: 1 week old. Now that you mention it, that's not right, but that do not explain the strange charging/discharging behavior.

Comment: I would unplug the AC, and with one of the new batteries installed, run it until the power drops and the computer shuts off. Then recharge it, without interruption, until full, and see if things change.

Comment: @heynnema I did that too. I also deplete the battery and start to charge it without turn on the laptop. But I will try again.